# Remove duplicate value from nested object using javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a million of contacts which is from different group. For example

```
    {"GROUP":[{'G1: [C1,C2,C3........C500000]},
             {'G2': [C1,C2,C3........C500000,D1,D2,D3........D500000]}
.....]
    }
```

G1 has 500k contacts, G2 has 1 million contacts out of it 500k contacts which is already present in G1.

I want to filter above group object based on the condition,
"Contact which is already in any group should be checked and remove from  respective group".

Expected Result

```
 {"GROUP":[{'G1: [C1,C2,C3........C500000]},
             {'G2': [D1,D2,D3........D500000]},....]
    }
```

Here Group and its contact may increase in size.

What is the best way to implement it using lodash javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many items from previous object, will be included in the next, you can use `_.difference()` with an external array, which will store all existing items:

```js
var object = {
    group: [
        { g1: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']},
        { g2: ['c1', 'c4', 'c5', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']},
        { g3: ['c1', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'd1', 'd4', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5']}
    ]
};

var previousItems = [];

var group = object.group.map(function(item) {
  return _.mapValues(item, function(values) {
    var newValues = _.difference(values, previousItems);
    previousItems = previousItems.concat(newValues);
    return newValues;
  });
});

console.log(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If all items in the previous object are included in the next, you can use a simple `Array#slice`:

```js
var object = {
    group: [
        { g1: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']},
        { g2: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']},
        { g3: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5']}
    ]
};

var prevValues = [];

var group = object.group.map(function(item, index) {
  return _.mapValues(item, function(values) {
    var newValues = values.slice(prevValues.length);
    prevValues = values;
    return newValues;
  });
});

console.log(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works well...I have checked few contacts not 500 millions... Hope it will work well for million contact with great performance.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the client can't handle million contacts, and even if it does, the performance won't be great at all. You'll probably have to partition the handling to several webworkers. This kind of stuff should be handled by the server.

Comment: Yes doing it in node js using elastic search api with from index and size :)

Answer (score 1):

After a long process of thinking, i have this for you:

It automatically goes throught the object / array structure and removes the duplicated strings in the array of g1, g2, g3, ... and so on.

I never used lodash, so here is vanilla js.

```js
var object = {
    group: [
        { g1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']},
        { g2: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']},
        { g3: ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']}
    ]
};

var duplicateArray = [];

for(var key in object) {
  var group = object[key];
  
  for(var x = 0; x < group.length; x++) {
      var subGroup = group[x];
      
      for(var subkey in subGroup) {
          var contentArray = subGroup[subkey];
          
          for(var y = 0; y < contentArray.length; y++) {
              var value = contentArray[y];
          
              if(duplicateArray.indexOf(value) == -1) {
                  duplicateArray.push(value);
              } else {
                  object[key][x][subkey].splice(y, 1);
                  y -= 1;
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

console.log(`dub ${duplicateArray}`);
console.log(object);
```